# How to get data from rest service when using angular2 server rendering

Tags: rest, http, angular

I have a simple component that retrieves data from the server.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
  <h1>HEllo {{category}}</h1>
  `,
  providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    CategoryService
  ]
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  private category;
  constructor(private _categoryService: CategoryService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => this.category = categories.name);
  }
}
```

And my service looks like

```
@Injectable()
export default class CategoryService {
  constructor(private http: Http){}

  private _categoriesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/photo';
  getCategories() {
    return this.http.get(this._categoriesUrl)
                    .map(res => return res.json().data;)
                    .do(data => console.log(data))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

It works well when I'm rendering it on client side but when I'm using angular2-universal-preview for rendering it on server side it throws an error

```
XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

How could I make it working with server side rendering?

Comment: APART FROM ANSWER JUST TIP :- its better to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` at the time of bootstrap instead of providing in each component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
  providers: [
    NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    CategoryService
  ]
```

See also https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/292

I think it would be better to add `NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS])` instead of each (or some components) except when you have a good reason to request different instances of `Http` for each component.

Comment: As far as I understood I have to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from `angular2/http` when bootstrapping on client side and `NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS` from `angular2-universal-preview` when bootstrapping with server rendering.
When I did this change the app started to work but the data was not fetched on server side instead the request was made on client.
Does it suppose to work this way? Cause I expected that page should be completely loaded on server side and no requests should be made on client side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about server side rendering. I just stumbled over this NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS.